# Use tabularx in LyX instead of default tabular

Tags: tables, lyx

I recently got into LyX and I’m getting along quite well.

The only thing that bothers me is that LyX’s table feature produces really sloppy-looking tables by default, i.e. double borders and stuff like that.

I would love to tell LyX to use the `tabularx` environment by default for the tables I enter via the GUI element, so I can get tables with 100% width matching the justified paragraphs. Concerning the borders, I would like to remove all of them but a `\toprule` above and beneath the first row of the table and a `\bottomrule` beneath the last row. These features are added by the `ctable` package which is included in my document preamble. Is there any way I can achieve these things without performing crazy stuff like regex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

write into the preamble of your document (document->settings->preamble)

```
\usepackage{array}
\def\tabular{%
 \setlength\dimen@{\linewidth}%
   \edef\@halignto{to\the\dimen@}\@tabular}
\newcolumntype{C}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c}
```

then all tables are by default converted into `tabular*`. Choose for the first column the column type C or write alternetively the definition `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c` for the first column via the tabular menu

Comment: This seems to be a good starting point, but instead of evenly spacing out the colums of my 3-column-table, this just adds a fourth, empty column covering the remaining text area. Note that the author line in the heading is awkwardly aligned as well.

Comment: with `tabular*` you can not stretch all columns. See edited example. However, I suppose, that you want the `tabularx` instead of `tabular*`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it was really the `tabularx` environment I was looking for. I used `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}` without your custom preamble to create the effect I was looking for. But nevertheless, LyX won’t format tables inserted via the GUI this way and I couldn’t wrap my head around the border issue, yet. Seems like I will stick to entering code for my tables instead of using the GUI. If only one could use CSS to manipulate the PDF output, I would know exactly what to do! But anyways, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could perform the following two global replacement operations:

- replace all "`\end{tabular}`" strings with "`\end{tabular*}`"
- replace all "`\begin{tabular}{`" strings with "`\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`"

Regarding the replacment of the `\hline` commands with `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`: Whether it's possible to do a global search-and-replace  will depend greatly on how you've entered the `\hline` commands so far. Without detailed knowledge of this aspect, I can't give a suggestion for how to perform this step.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think you misinterpreted / I misformulated my question. I can of course enter the right TeX code to produce the tables the way I want them to look, but my intention is to „tell“ LyX to use this code for the tables I entered via the GUI automatically, i.e. without having to enter any TeX code. I will update my question to reflect these goals.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tabularx` instead of `tabular*`?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk - Not really. :-) The `tabularx` and `tabular*` environments both serve to generate tables with a pre-set width (often `\textwidth`, as in the present case), but they achieve the goal in different ways. The former achieves the goal by changing the widths of certain columns -- those of type `X`, to be precise -- whereas the latter operates by changing the amount of intercolumn whitespace (that's what `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`directive is all about). It's a bit confusing, honestly, because the posting was edited to focus on `tabularx`, but only *after* I had posted my answer...